# Copy Selected Columns in One Sheet and Add Them To Selected Columns in Another Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I would like to create a simple google apps script to copy specific column into another sheets.
Previously I tried using getLastRow but I get stuck to modify it.

```
var destinationSheetLastRow = destinationSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
```

Here is my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rGvmlKCmbjDSCLCC2Kujft5e4ngbSLzJd2NYu0sxISs/edit?usp=sharing

And here is the modified script so far:

```js
function pasteMultiCol(sourceSheet, destinationSheet,sourceColumns,destinationColumns, doneColumn){
 
  var sourceDataRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  var sourceDataValues = sourceDataRange.getValues();
  var sourcesheetFirstRow = 0;
  var sourceSheetLastRow = sourceDataRange.getLastRow();
   
  var destinationSheetLastRow = destinationSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  
  var pendingCount = 0;
  
  //Find the row start for copying
  for(i = 0; i < sourceDataValues.length; i++){
    if(sourceDataValues[i][doneColumn-1] === "Copied"){
        sourcesheetFirstRow++;
    };
    if(sourceDataValues[i][doneColumn-1] === ""){
        pendingCount++;
    };
  };
  
  //Update Source sheet first row to take into account the header
  var header = sourceSheetLastRow-(sourcesheetFirstRow + pendingCount);  
  sourcesheetFirstRow = sourcesheetFirstRow+header;
  
  // if the first row equals the last row then there is no data to paste. 
  if(sourcesheetFirstRow === sourceSheetLastRow){return};
  
  var sourceSheetRowLength = sourceSheetLastRow - sourcesheetFirstRow;
  
  //Iterate through each column
  for(i = 0; i < destinationColumns.length; i++){
      var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheetLastRow+1,
                                                       destinationColumns[i],
                                                       sourceSheetRowLength,
                                                       1);
      var sourceValues = sourceDataValues.slice(sourcesheetFirstRow-1,sourceSheetLastRow);
      var columnValues =[]
      for(j = header; j < sourceValues.length; j++){
        columnValues.push([sourceValues[j][sourceColumns[i]-1]]);
      };
      destinationRange.setValues(columnValues);
  };
  
  //Change Source Sheet to Copied.
  var copiedArray =[];
  for(i=0; i<sourceSheetRowLength; i++){copiedArray.push(["Copied"])};
  
  var copiedRange = sourceSheet.getRange(sourcesheetFirstRow+1,doneColumn,sourceSheetRowLength,1)
  copiedRange.setValues(copiedArray);
 
  
};
 
function runsies(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1snMyf8YZZ0cGlbMIvZY-fAXrI_dJpPbl7rKcYCkPDpk");
  var source = ss.getSheetByName("Source");
  var destination = ss.getSheetByName("Destination");
    
  var sourceCols = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
  var destinationCols = [7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
  
  var doneCol = 12
  
  //Run our copy and append function
  pasteMultiCol(source,destination, sourceCols, destinationCols, doneCol);
};
```

Comment: I wouldn't mind helping you if you provide images of your source and destination sheets so that I can see their unique nature.  I realize that you have provided a link to your spreadsheet but I don't follow such links.  Your question has been view 25 times which is quite a lot but as yet still no answers.  So you might want to consider adding images of your pages.  If not, I understand but I also won't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: Apart from the fact that `doneCol` should be `11` instead of `12`, can you please clarify how you want to specify which rows to copy to? Is all the data always going to be copied  to a group of contiguous rows, in which case you would only need to retrieve the first row of the target range (I don't know how you would want to identify this row), or you want to check the `Code` or the `Item name` in order to know where to copy which rows to? All this is not clear in your question, I'd suggest you to clarify this if you want to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is taken from my tutorial in my blog article [Copy Selected Columns in One Sheet and Add Them To The Bottom of Different Selected Columns in Another Sheet](https://yagisanatode.com/2018/11/17/google-apps-script-copy-selected-columns-in-one-sheet-and-add-them-to-the-bottom-of-different-selected-columns-in-another/) and it just needs a tweak.

I think the issue might be that you have a bunch of formulas in other columns in your "Destination" Sheet tab. So getting the last row of the sheet will result in getting the last row considering all the data including your other formulas.

You might find this explanation in a follow up blog article I wrote helpful: [Google Apps Script: Get the last row of a data range when other columns have content like hidden formulas and check boxes](https://yagisanatode.com/2019/05/11/google-apps-script-get-the-last-row-of-a-data-range-when-other-columns-have-content-like-hidden-formulas-and-check-boxes/)

In short, you can change the destinationSheetLastRow variable to something simple like this.

```
  var destinationSheetLastRow = (()=>{
    let destinationSheetFirstRow = 7; // The first row of data after your header. 
    //Get a sample range to find the last value in the paste columns.
    let sampleRange = destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheetFirstRow,
                                                destinationColumns[0],
                                                destinationSheet.getLastRow())
                                      .getValues();
     
     let sampleLastRow = 0;
     while(sampleLastRow < sampleRange.length){
       if (sampleRange[sampleLastRow][0] == ""){
         break;
       }
       sampleLastRow++;
     };
     return sampleLastRow;
  })()
```